# Drawing Curved dashed SVG Path on Scroll

Tags: javascript, css, svg, scroll

I am trying to create a curved dashed line that displays  on scroll. I have followed along to the tutorial on https://css-tricks.com/scroll-drawing/ . I made the svg a compound path but only the first curve draws on scroll.

I believe it is something with my path for my svg.

I created a codepen based on the original from css tricks.

https://codepen.io/stevejay12/pen/gOYWmPP

```
<p class="codepen" data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-default-tab="html,result" data-user="stevejay12" data-slug-hash="gOYWmPP" style="height: 265px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;" data-pen-title="Scroll Drawing">
  <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/stevejay12/pen/gOYWmPP/">
  Scroll Drawing</a> by stevejay12 (<a href="https://codepen.io/stevejay12">@stevejay12</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

The end result should be similar to this http://rickriordan.com/ .

Comment: The dash patterns start at the beginning of each subpath. So each section of your line (being subpaths) draws at the same time.

You need to make the whole twisty path one continuous line.

Comment: Thanks Paul, so what your saying is the curves and circles have to be one element  in illustator? I tried to join them all but I got an error. I did make them a compound path.

Comment: It has to be one continuous path from start to end.  A compound path won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The dash patterns (the animations) start at the beginning of each subpath. So each section of your line - and each circle - (being subpaths) draws at the same time.

You need to make the whole twisty path one continuous line.  Don't break it up into seprate subpaths.

As for the circles. You'll need special handling for them. For instance, you could:

1. Keep them transparent, then make them visible at the right moments.
2. Have two paths that get animated the same, except that one passes round one side of the circles (one semicircle), and the other passes round the other side (the other semicircle).